# How to use IsolationForest for anomaly detection of a 1D-array, given given another feature?

Tags: unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

[Beginner at ML]
Hi,
I would like to use unsupervised anomaly detection of spectrograms.
Currently, I am trying IsolationForest on a bunch of 1D-arrays (light intensity vs wavelength) in order to detect which one is anomalous. Each 1D-array is associated with a plankton density value.

An anomaly should be defined as i) an abonormal spectrum relative to the other spectra, ii) an abonormal density value, or iii) abnormal spectrum and density. The output should flag only the abnormal spectrum.

I realized that whatever density value I give, the result does not change.

In the example showed below in the dataframe, spectrum 0 was (truely) detected as anomalous. However, I have given spectrum 7 an abnormal density value of 1500, and yet, it never appears as anomalous.

I must have something wrong, or, I need to apply weights to the density feature? Would you use another algorithm for this problem? Autoencoders ? Thanks for you insights.
[image: Data DataFrame. rows 0-7 = instances (I only showed 8 spectra here). Columns 316. to 886 nm : wavelengths. Column Density value = plankton density]
[image: Result of anomalous spectra detection (dotted red line). Spectrum 7 should also be anomalous due to its abnormal density value associated.]